# SOAP Web Service - Can't generate classes from XSD

Tags: java, web-services, web, soap, xsd

I've been following the exact steps from [this](http://www.springboottutorial.com/creating-soap-web-service-with-spring-boot-web-services-starter) tutorial. However, i keep getting the same error no matter what i try.

I have two elements that should be generated in the xsd file: GetStudentDetailsRequest and GetStudentDetailsResponse. Here is my .xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://in28minutes.com/students"
           xmlns:tns="http://in28minutes.com/students" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="GetStudentDetailsRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name= "id" type="xs:int"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="GetStudentDetailsResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name= "StudentDetails" type="tns:StudentDetails"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="StudentDetails">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="passportNumber" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

And my pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.in28minutes.springboot.soap.web.services.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-tutorial-soap-web-services</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <name>Assignment4OnlineTrackerSystem</name>
        <description>OnlineTrackerSystem</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

If i run mvn clean install i get the following error:

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:113)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BGMBuilder.<init>(BGMBuilder.java:147)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BGMBuilder.build(BGMBuilder.java:117)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.annotateXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:425)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:174)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:119)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:333)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.AbstractXjcMojo.execute(AbstractXjcMojo.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:102)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:113)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BindingComponent.getClassSelector(BindingComponent.java:65)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.ColorBinder.<init>(ColorBinder.java:62)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BindGreen.<init>(BindGreen.java:63)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:102)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/MimeTypeParseException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3138)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3343)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2554)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:100)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.DefaultClassBinder.<init>(DefaultClassBinder.java:98)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.ClassSelector.<init>(ClassSelector.java:214)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 50 more
```

I've seen some suggestions to switch from java 9 to java 8, try a different jdk, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your javax.activation dependency with the correct artifactId. it is javax.activation not just activation

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise, using jdk 1.8 would solve the issue as it will use the jdk's version of javax.activation.

Tested with jdk1.8 with your current pom and it worked
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/

However, with the jdk 1.9, you need to update the pom as above to get it working.

Comment: The solution for jdk 1.9 didn't work, but i switched to jdk 1.8 and it got rid of the error. Thank you!