# SOAP web Service with Springboot - Can't generate classes from XSD

Tags: spring-boot, soap, java-8, soap-client

I am getting following error when generating POJO classes using xsd:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:113)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BGMBuilder.<init>(BGMBuilder.java:147)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BGMBuilder.build(BGMBuilder.java:117)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.annotateXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:425)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:174)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:119)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:333)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.AbstractXjcMojo.execute(AbstractXjcMojo.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:79)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:102)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:113)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BindingComponent.getClassSelector(BindingComponent.java:65)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.ColorBinder.<init>(ColorBinder.java:62)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BindGreen.<init>(BindGreen.java:63)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:79)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:102)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/MimeTypeParseException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3405)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3610)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2786)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:100)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.DefaultClassBinder.<init>(DefaultClassBinder.java:98)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.ClassSelector.<init>(ClassSelector.java:214)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 48 more
```

This is a springboot project, and I have already added jakarta.activation-api in pom. Below is part of pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I have already looked into these solutions, but are not working:
[SOAP Web Service - Can't generate classes from XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53697815/soap-web-service-cant-generate-classes-from-xsd)
[What is the replacement for javax.activation package in java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493613/what-is-the-replacement-for-javax-activation-package-in-java-9)
I am using java 8, and following this tutorial:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-soap-web-service

Any help is appreciated.

Compilation is successful after adding  in pom.xml. But, still Java POJO classes are not generated. Below is the path available in pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>xjc</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>xjc</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: which `spring-boot` version do you use?

Comment: version- 2.7.3.

Answer (score 1):

So, I was able to fix the issue by following these 2 steps:

1. install Jakarta EE: Web Services ​(JAX-WS)​ plugin to Intellij.
2. follow this to generate the java classes:
   https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-java-from-xml-schema-using-jaxb-dialog.html